# Create local storage (device, not cache) with Ionicframework

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm developing an app using the ionic framework running with cordova aswell that requires me to save some data in the user's device (Android/iOS) local storage (ex. SD) and I can't save it using the localStorage of ionic framework because it saves the data in the cache.

In other others i need my data to persist in the device for a long period of time.

What other solutions do i have ?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/ might help.

Comment: @Phonolog That way i'll still be using cache, on browser, but its still cache :/

Comment: It's pretty much an overview over different possibilities to persist data, if you want to write to the file system/sd-card of the user, see [this section](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/#file-access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 **web storage** (i.e. localStorage) is not always a bad option. It is a readily available key value storage that is widely supported. And no, it is not stored *exactly* in a cache i.e. data in localStorage does not *expire* nor is randomly wiped off. But is a limited and low priority storage, the exact specifics varying from platform to platform.

That said, we have the following more reliable alternatives, depending on what exactly you are trying to store:

1. **Native SQLite** - 
   As a Cordova app, your app has access to create and use a native SQLite database just like native mobile apps, via a third party [SQLite Plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage). From JavaScript, you would access your data just like you would access WebSQL outside Cordova. Ionic/ngCordova helps here by providing utility wrapper around the SQLite Plugin: $cordovaSQLite
2. **Native FileSystem** - 
   As a Cordova app, your app has access to the local file storage (also, on the SD card in Android, if that's where the user has stored the app's container) via the standard [File Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file). Again, Ionic provides a utility wrapper around it with many useful functions: $cordovaFile (check ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/)

IndexedDB is also worth mentioning here. Not a native mobile solution, but this noSQL storage is fast becoming the standard for large and reliable browser-side storage, marking WebSQL obsolete. However, iOS web view has buggy and incomplete support for IndexedDB (caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb)

Pick your solution depending on WHAT is the data you want to store. For storing application data I use a combination of Native SQLite (for structured data) and localStorage (for key value data, mostly UI preferences). For storing resources, there's always the FileSystem.

Comment: If you just want something similar to localStorage i.e. key value pairs of data, you can create your own file and read through it. If the data is intended to be your application's preferences, there also a [Preferences Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/preferences/) providing similar key value storage.

Comment: NOTE: If you want your data to persist even after the app is uninstalled, I am afraid you have limited options. I can only imagine you doing so if you store your data in a file outside the app container in a public directory using either the File Plugin or the Preferences Plugin (check the above links for both to see how). Everything else is destined to be wiped off along with the app :-)